# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in system/libraries/Email.php on line 2269 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have used mail function in a loop condition. I have Used

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');
```

in  __construct() function.

And my mail function is

```
$this->email->from('from@domain.com', 'fromname');
$this->email->to('to@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('subject');
$this->email->message('content_with_header');
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->send();
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
```

The mail function is executed at first time in loop. After that it is showing error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in
>   **/home4/deanjobs/public_html/mywebsite/system/libraries/Email.php on line 2269**

Can anybody help me to fix this error?

Comment: Are you calling `$this->load->library('email');` inside a custom class ?

Comment: No, I have used within __construct() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not call the constructor of parent controller class.

`parent::__construct();`

Try swapping these lines:
Your code: 
`$this->load->library('email');
$this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');`

Should be:
`$this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');
$this->load->library('email');`

Comment: No, i have used 
function __construct() 
{
 parent::__construct();
 $this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl'); 
}

Comment: ok. Try swapping these lines:
Your code: 
`$this->load->library('email');
$this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');`

Should be:
`$this->lang = $this->uri->segment(2, 'nl');
$this->load->library('email');`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class extends `CI_Controller` if it's a controller.

If your class is a library, you need to load Codeigniter application instance

```
function __construct() 
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('email');
    $this->CI->lang = $this->CI->uri->segment(2, 'nl');
}
```

And inside your mail function

```
$this->CI->email->from('from@domain.com', 'fromname');
$this->CI->email->to('to@gmail.com'); 
$this->CI->email->subject('subject');
$this->CI->email->message('content_with_header');
$this->CI->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->CI->email->send();
$this->CI->email->clear(TRUE);
```